# Convert "04.05.2003 23:00:00.000 GMT+0200" to date variable in R

Tags: r, date, as.date

I have a vector representing time such as:

```
 1. 04.05.2003 23:00:00.000 GMT+0200
 2. 04.05.2003 23:00:00.000 GMT+0200
 3. 04.05.2003 23:30:00.000 GMT+0200
 4. 04.05.2003 23:45:00.000 GMT+0200
```

I want to have a date variable representing the day and within-day variation, and I tried to convert it to a date variable in R using:

`as.POSIXct(variable,format="%d.%b.%Y %H:%M:%OS %Z")`

But I've got an empty cell. I can't figure out how to convert it.

Comment: It was an accident Ronak. My apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lubridate::dmy_hms` :

```
variable <- c('4.05.2003 23:00:00.000 GMT+0200','04.05.2003 23:15:00.000 GMT+0200', '04.05.2003 23:30:00.000 GMT+0200')
variable  <- lubridate::dmy_hms(variable)
variable

#[1] "2003-05-04 21:00:00 UTC" "2003-05-04 21:15:00 UTC" "2003-05-04 21:30:00 UTC"
```

Comment: It generates correctly the date for this example. Do you know how I could generalize this function to a vector: `4.05.2003 23:00:00.000 GMT+0200

04.05.2003 23:15:00.000 GMT+0200

04.05.2003 23:30:00.000 GMT+0200

04.05.2003 23:45:00.000 GMT+0200

05.05.2003 00:00:00.000 GMT+0200

05.05.2003 00:15:00.000 GMT+0200

05.05.2003 00:30:00.000 GMT+0200`

Comment: @Marc Function works with a vector as well. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the time zone but you are using `%b` where you should be using `%m`:

```
as.POSIXct(variable,format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%OS")
# "2003-05-04 23:00:00 GMT"
```